# Is it a problem that the entire element in my electric oven is not red?

Tags: oven

I have a Maytag MER6770AAW twin ovens 4 burner stove.  The bottom burner only turns red  around the front, and not at the back.  One end going into the back turns red and runs all the way around except across the complete back and returning into the back. Is this a problem?

The element disconnect checks out for continuity.

Comment: Pictures? It's normal for the last 2-3 inches on both ends near the connector block to be black.

Comment: If you disconnected the element, can you also swap elements?